# I am using ImageSwitcher. When I run the file I'm getting the following error:

Tags: android, imageswitcher

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import com.example.app38.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {

    LinearLayout linearLayoutHorizontal;
    ImageSwitcher imgSwitcher;

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

        linearLayoutHorizontal = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutHorizontal);
        imgSwitcher = findViewById(R.id.imgSwitcher);

        imgSwitcher.setFactory(MainActivity.this);

        imgSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
        imgSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out));

        for (int index = 0; index < Animal.animalImages.length; index++) {
            final int i = index;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            imageView.setImageResource(Animal.animalImages[index]);
            letsSetlayoutParamsForImageView(imageView);
            imageView.setPadding(100,100,100,100);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                imgSwitcher.setImageResource(Animal.animalImages[i]);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is "+ Animal.animalNames[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            linearLayoutHorizontal.addView(imageView);
        }
    }

    public void letsSetlayoutParamsForImageView(ImageView imageView) {
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(1000,1000));
    }

    @Override
    public View makeView() {
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imgView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        return imgView;
    }
}
```

**Animal.java**

```
public class Animal {

    static int[] animalImages = { R.drawable.bear, R.drawable.bird, R.drawable.cat, R.drawable.cow,
    R.drawable.dolphin, R.drawable.fish, R.drawable.fox, R.drawable.horse, R.drawable.lion, R.drawable.tiger};

    static String[] animalNames = {"Bear","Bird","Cat","Cow","Dolphin","Fish","Fox","Horse","Lion","Tiger"};


}
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHorizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </HorizontalScrollView>

                <ImageSwitcher
                    android:id="@+id/imgSwitcher"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageSwitcher>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat**

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.app38, PID: 14499
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app38/com.example.app38.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
at android.widget.ViewSwitcher.obtainView(ViewSwitcher.java:86)
at android.widget.ViewSwitcher.setFactory(ViewSwitcher.java:104)
at com.example.app38.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

The line of code at line 33:

imgSwitcher.setFactory(MainActivity.this);

Can any one suggest a answer for my problem.

Comment: This is caused by a typo, solved by @Hamed. I suggest reading at least the first five lines of your logcat next time! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
imgView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

to

```
imgView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```